# IList does not contain a definition <linq function>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `IList`

```
IList list = GetList();
```

and want to use Linq function on it like `FirstOrDefault()` or `Where()` but it says:

> IList does not contain a definition for [linq function]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your collection does not implement the generic interfaces you can use the `Cast` or `OfType`(Cast + Filter) extension methods.

```
IList list = GetList();
string first = list.Cast<string>().FirstOrDefault();
```

You can use these methods with anything that implements `IEnumerable`. Of course it works only if the list really contains strings. If it could contain anything you could use:

```
string first = list.Cast<Object>().Select(obj => obj?.ToString() ?? "").FirstOrDefault();
```

If you just want objects that are strings you can use `OfType` as mentioned above:

```
string first = list.OfType<string>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you are using the **generic** `IList` with the type you use like this

```
IList<string> list = GetList();
```

Then you can use LINQ functions on that list.

Comment: If you *do* start with a non-generic collection, `Cast<T>()` and `OfType<T>()` are your friends.